# Changing environment variables for Docker existing container instance - using Docker Desktop with WSL2

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to change environment variable "RAM" to **8**, so basically upgrade the container to 8GB of RAM for a specific existing container.

The way the variable was originally set was through `docker run -e RAM=4`  command for example. However, if I run "dock run" again it creates another container instance. I don't want to do this because I have already setup/configured the OS in the original container.

Is there anyway to change this environment variable for the container without creating a new container?  By the way I'm using Docker for Windows with WSL2

The below is section from *docker inspect*

```
"Env": [
                "DISPLAY=172.16.22.8:0.0",
                "EXTRA=-display none -vnc 0.0.0.0:99,password=off",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=en_US.UTF-8",
                "USER=arch",
                "SUPERMIN_KERNEL=/boot/vmlinuz-linux",
                "SUPERMIN_MODULES=/lib/modules/5.12.14-arch1-1",
                "SUPERMIN_KERNEL_VERSION=5.12.14-arch1-1",
                "KERNEL_PACKAGE_URL=https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.12.14.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst",
                "KERNEL_HEADERS_PACKAGE_URL=https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-headers-5.12.14.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst",
                "LIBGUESTFS_PACKAGE_URL=https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/libguestfs/libguestfs-1.44.1-6-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst",
                "LIBGUESTFS_DEBUG=1",
                "LIBGUESTFS_TRACE=1",
                "ADDITIONAL_PORTS=",
                "BASESYSTEM_FORMAT=qcow2",
                "BOOT_ARGS=",
                "BOOTDISK=",
                "CPU=Penryn",
                "CPUID_FLAGS=vendor=GenuineIntel,+invtsc,vmware-cpuid-freq=on,+ssse3,+sse4.2,+popcnt,+avx,+aes,+xsave,+xsaveopt,check,",
                "ENV=/env",
                "GENERATE_UNIQUE=false",
                "GENERATE_SPECIFIC=false",
                "IMAGE_PATH=/home/arch/OSX-KVM/mac_hdd_ng.img",
                "IMAGE_FORMAT=qcow2",
                "KVM=accel=kvm:tcg",
                "MASTER_PLIST_URL=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sickcodes/osx-serial-generator/master/config-custom.plist",
                "NETWORKING=vmxnet3",
                "NOPICKER=false",
                "RAM=4",
                "WIDTH=1920",
                "HEIGHT=1080"
            ],
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not meant to overwrite environment variables for a running container, you should just stop the running one and start a new one with new environment variables :)
Containers are supposed to be throw-away things anyway!